# How to pluralize in rails with words?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-i18n

I'd like to pluralize a translation with words for the numbers instead of numerals.

So, for example, I'd like to be able to have a translation that results in:

```
"The Patriots came back to win the Superbowl by scoring thirty-one points in a row."
```

...instead of:

```
"The Patriots came back to win the Superbowl by scoring 31 points in a row."
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]" and the linked pages and "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)". Your question isn't asked well. Did you search? If not why? If so, where and why didn't it help? Did you write code? If not, why? If so, what is the minimum code necessary to demonstrate the problem you're asking about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [humanize](https://github.com/radar/humanize):

```
2.humanize  # => "two"
4.humanize  # => "four"
8.humanize  # => "eight"
```

Or in your case:

```
str = "The Patriots came back to win the Superbowl by scoring 31 points in a row."
humanized = str.gsub(/\d+/) do |match|
  match.to_i.humanize  
end    
humanized # => "The Patriots came back to win the Superbowl by scoring thirty-one points in a row."
```

Comment: In your example, you're using already humanized string. And your regex is off.

Comment: Oops, my bad.. what do you mean by "regex is off"?

Comment: It doesn't do what you think it would. :) Try it.

Comment: Good catch tho! Don't know how I messed it up that it would print thirty-one in the first place.. @SergioTulentsev the regex now should be okay, right?

Comment: Yes, better now!

Comment: "Don't know how I messed it up" - Your string was humanized to begin with, and then the regex did nothing